# Python httplib.HTTPSConnection with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, httplib

I would like to send a Get request from python's httplib library, using HTTPS protocol.

I have already went through multiple answers suggesting how to do it when using http protocol, but they didn't work with https.

here's my code to defile an HTTPSConnection.

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(server, port=port, context=ssl_context)
connection.request("GET", path, None, headers)
```

I haven't included any proxy server yet in this code. If someone could tell me how to send this request with a proxy server (say : x.x.x.x:8080), it would be great help.

**Update 1:** 
I tried the following code-

```
import httplib
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection("10.136.8.10", port=8080, context=ssl_context)
conn.set_tunnel("registry-1.docker.io", port=port)
conn.request("GET", "/", None, headers) 
resp = conn.getresponse()
print resp1.status
```

Still not working getting error 503.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried to connect to proxy through `HTTPSConnection` method, but it works with `HTTPConnection`. Any way, try to do this:

```
connection = httplib.HTTPSConnection(proxy_server, port=port, context=ssl_context)
connection.set_tunnel(url, port) # usually port is 443
connection.request("GET", "/", None, headers)
```

Comment: It gave me this error: Tunnel connection failed: 405 Method Not Allowed

Comment: All right, So I am now testing this part on python console. I tried what the updated code, but get this error: "CannotSendRequest:"

Comment: Please check the Update1 in my question.